# Commons Math - could not find class org.apache.commons

Tags: android, math, apache-commons, apache-commons-math

I have downloaded the binary Zip from [here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/download_math.cgi). I extracted the zip to a folder. Then I right clicked on `libs` folder in Eclipse. I Imported the *.jar file to the `libs` folder, and then I right clicked on it and `added to path`. I added

```
 import org.apache.commons.math3.stat.descriptive.DescriptiveStatistics;
```

to my java file, and i am adding values to

```
DescriptiveStatistics rStandardDeviation = new DescriptiveStatistics();
```

and after that I run the math part by:

```
double bMean = bStandardDeviation.getMean();
double rStd = rStandardDeviation.getStandardDeviation();
```

No errors on compile, clean, or build. When I attempt to run the app on my phone i get:

```
Could not find class 'org.apache.commons.math3.stat.descriptive.DescriptiveStatistics', referenced from method com.example.mydemo.MainActivity.<init>
```

Any ideas anyone what is going wrong?

Thank you

Comment: You actually shouldn't need to do the add to path step if you're on the latest ADT. Just putting the library in the libs folder should be sufficient.

Comment: What solution do you think will work? Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Good question, reduced code and specific question. Upvote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your Build Configuration, make sure you check your library to be exported in Order and Export. See

[image]

Comment: Putting the jar in the libs folder should be sufficient. If you look in a normal Android project (which your screenshot is not of) you should see an item for Android dependencies in Order and Export which automatically takes care of it for you.

Comment: What fixed it for me was removing all the paths that i added, and deleting all the folders/files i added. Then actually place the jar file in the Libs folder. Then in eclipse, I refreshed the package explorer, and `added to path` the jar file from there. Not sure what I did wrong before hand, but that jsut fixed it all.